# .net Determine at run time whether my app is an exe or a web app

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-3.5, environment-variables

I'm sure I have done this before in the past, but I've been in the docs for a bit, and can't seem to find it again.  I need to be able to determine at run time in my business domain what context my application is running in.  So that I may do some switching with config files, and use the proper method to determine if I am running in debug or release etc.  I was pretty confident it was in System.Environment, but I have not come across it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very easy method:

```
bool isWebApp = HttpContext.Current != null;
```

Works like a charm every time.

Comment: Note that I don't think this will work from inside a worker thread that has been fired off by the web app. In that case though, you could probably pass in a preset variable.

Answer (score 4):

I found the way I had done it earlier finally.

```
bool isWebApp = System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainId != null;
```

It's much the same as Nathan's response though.  Thanks for the reply.